# ArchLinux on Virtualbox SSH session disconnects randomly

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, archlinux

Recently I installed newest Oracle VirtualBox with an intent to install ArchLinux on it and use it as a personal ssh terminal (I really like to work on Windows with MobaXterm terminal and mapped network directory to SFTP connection).
I then installed ArchLinux following this guide ( http://wideaperture.net/blog/?p=3851 ) until step 15. (figured that I don't need any desktop and/or VB guest additions).

It worked more or less flawless until I actually started to use this virtual machine as ssh terminal - configured VirtualBox NAT to accept ssh connections on desired port and it worked at first glance.

Except that it didn't - whether it's SSH or SFTP connection, it just gets disconnected randomly after a few minutes - "Server unexpectedly closed network connection".
I tried configuring sshd_config file to keep session alive (as was suggested by many google results) but nothing seems to work.

Am I missing something (possibly something terribly obvious)?

In advance: thank you very much for help, any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Keep a ping running in another window and see if there's any hiccups.

Comment: Using ping didn't show any anomalies, but I managed to help myself by changing virtual environment from VirtualBox to VM Player. It now works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by changing from VirtualBox to VMware Player.